# Causal Inference in a employee churn context (difference-in-differences / Propensity score matching)

Tags: causality, propensity-scores, difference-in-difference, observational-study

For my master thesis I'm trying to determine the causes of an employee leaving a company. Currently I'm trying to study the effect that giving a raise has on employee leaving a company or not. So my treatment variable would be giving a raise or not and my outcome variable would be the employee leaving the company or not.

In this company the raises are given in August, and I have data from the past 4 years with information about the employees (including which ones left the company) before and after the raises are given. Since I can not make a randomized control trial (for a number of obvious reasons) I looked at causal inference for observational data and techniques such as difference-in-differences and propensity score matching.

The problem is: Since the I want to study the effect of givin a raise I have to consider employees that remained in the company until August (when the raises are given) and so there are no employees leaving the company before the treatment, invalidating the difference-in-differences/Propensity score matching study

How could I analyse the average treatment effect of givin a raise on the decision of a person leaving the company or not in this situation?

Thank you!

Comment: My questions may be naive but you have only those two variables? And raise is a boolean variable? or percentage (like this employee get 1% raise this year).

Comment: @PauZen I have nearly 40 variables (age, gender, position etc.) and I have two variable for the raise (a boolean one and one that tells me the percentage of the raise), although in this particular analysis I was only interest in determining the effect of giving a raise and not really the percentage amount of raise.